# Is Paley-13 graph a unit distance graph in 3D space?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, coloring, open-problem, extremal-combinatorics

The 13-node [Paley graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PaleyGraph.html) has vertices 1 to 13 that are connected by an edge when their difference is one of the values

$(1,3,4,9,10,12)$

Can this graph be put into 3D space so that all edges have length 1, making it a [unit distance graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Unit-DistanceGraph.html)?  The graph has chromatic number 5, so this would be a nice object for the 3D [Hadwiger–Nelson problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem).

Comment: I like this question.  See [here](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/genus/1/t13.png) for a nice drawing of this graph on a torus.

Comment: By the way, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem#Variations_of_the_problem), it is known that the chromatic number of 3D space is at least six.  Doesn't that make this graph irrelevant to the Hadwiger-Nelson problem?

Comment: I'm trying to compile unit distance graphs with chromatic number 5. I'm hoping I can use them to build a graph with chromatic number 6, and that can be used to bump the lower bound to 7.

Comment: A dimension count makes it seem unlikely.  13 vertices in Euclidean space have $3V - 6 = 33$ degrees of freedom (modulo isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$).  The Paley-13 graph has $39$ edges, so generically we shouldn't get to decide all of the edge lengths.

Comment: If it were embeddable, it would be a be a non-convex [deltahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron) of [genus one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_polyhedron).

Comment: Actually, I think my dimension count argument above is completely unconvincing.  The same argument holds for *any* deltahedron of genus one: since such a polyhedron must satisfy $2E=3F$ and $V-E+F=0$, we always get $3V - E=0$.  But of course deltahedra of genus one do exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No such embedding exists.** The proof below is not fully rigorous, but should be convincing enough.

Number the vertices like this:

[image]

As in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3955860/357390) I am going to explicitly construct the graph's vertices starting from a few parameters. The following parameters suffice in this case:

- The angles $\angle1,0,3$, $\angle3,0,9$, $\angle9,0,1$. All must lie in $(0,2\pi/3]$ (otherwise the points $4,12,10$ cannot be constructed) and they must satisfy the triangle inequality.
- Whether the points $4,12,10$ are constructed "above" ($+$) or "below" $(-)$ the $0,1,3,9$ plane (just like there are in general two solutions for a point at unit distance from two other points *in the plane*, so there are in general two solutions for a point at unit distance from *three* other points in 3D space).

By symmetry we can reduce the eight possibilities for the second set of parameters to four: $+++,++-,+--,---$. Without loss of generality we can also fix $0=(0,0,0)$, $1=(1,0,0)$, point $3$ in the $xy$-plane and point $9$ with positive $z$-coordinate – the parameters above then fix points $4,12,10$.

The remaining six points are *uniquely* determined. To see this, note that $0$ and $2$ are both adjacent to $1,3,12$; with all distances identical and the requirement that vertices not coincide it is easy to deduce that point $2$ must be the reflection of point $0$ in the $1,3,12$ plane. A similar argument applies by rotating the diagram above for the other five "outer" points.

---

To actually show the non-existence of a 3D unit-distance embedding for Paley-13 we sample over all possible combinations of parameters. For each sample we compute the sum of absolute deviations from $1$ of the nine remaining edges:
$$\{(2, 11), (8, 5), (6, 7), (2, 6), (8, 11), (6, 5), (11, 7), (5, 2), (7, 8)\}$$
If Paley-13 had a unit-distance embedding we would expect some samples to have a deviation sum close to zero, but sampling the continuous parameters using a dense lattice yields the following minimal sums for each sign pattern:
$$+++:1.2676384880260365\\
++-:1.6056266375770387\\
+--:1.2143797215919396\\
---:1.5513409497822102$$
All are far from zero, so we conclude that the Paley graph of order $13$ has no 3D unit-distance embedding.

---

This is the program I used to derive the minimal deviation sums above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np

L = 2*np.pi/3
eps = 1e-6
res = 200
coord = np.linspace(eps, L-eps, res+1)
A, B, C = np.meshgrid(coord, coord, coord, indexing="ij")

def tripod(p, q):
    # Construct the point at distance 1 from 0, p and q
    # such that from its perspective the vertices 0-p-q
    # run counterclockwise. Assume |p| = |q| = 1.
    diff = q-p
    d = (diff*diff).sum(axis=-1)[...,np.newaxis]
    k = diff / np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=-1)[...,np.newaxis]
    v = -(p+q) / 2
    kxv = np.cross(k, v)
    kdv = (k*v).sum(axis=-1)[...,np.newaxis]
    return 2 * (np.sqrt(3-d)*kxv + kdv*k - v) / (4-d)

def reflect(p, q, r):
    # Construct the reflection of the origin in the plane
    # defined by p, q, r.
    n = np.cross(q-p, r-p)
    proj = (n*p).sum(axis=-1) / (n*n).sum(axis=-1)
    return 2 * proj[...,np.newaxis] * n

def paleymin(signs):
    K0 = np.zeros_like(A)
    K1 = np.ones_like(A)
    p0 = np.stack([K0, K0, K0], axis=-1)
    p1 = np.stack([K1, K0, K0], axis=-1)
    p3 = np.stack([np.cos(C), np.sin(C), K0], axis=-1)
    dh = (np.cos(A) - np.cos(B)*np.cos(C)) / (np.sin(B)*np.sin(C))
    np.clip(dh, -1, 1, dh)
    p9 = np.stack([np.cos(B), dh*np.sin(B), np.sqrt(1-dh**2)*np.sin(B)], axis=-1)
    p4 = tripod(p1, p3) if signs < 1 else tripod(p3, p1)
    p12 = tripod(p3, p9) if signs < 2 else tripod(p9, p3)
    p10 = tripod(p9, p1) if signs < 3 else tripod(p1, p9)
    p2 = reflect(p1, p3, p12)
    p8 = reflect(p4, p12, p9)
    p6 = reflect(p3, p9, p10)
    p11 = reflect(p12, p10, p1)
    p5 = reflect(p9, p1, p4)
    p7 = reflect(p10, p4, p3)
    pts = [p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12]
    test_edges = ((2, 11), (8, 5), (6, 7), (2, 6), (8, 11), (6, 5), (11, 7), (5, 2), (7, 8))
    distances = sum(abs(np.linalg.norm(pts[i]-pts[j], axis=-1) - 1) for (i,j) in test_edges)
    return distances.min()

for s in range(4):
    print(s, paleymin(s))
```

Comment: I wonder whether the following idea works: it is known that the 13-vertex Paley graph needs at least six dimensions for an embedding that is as symmetric as the graph. Can you show by some of your arguments in the first part that if there is a 3-dimensional embedding, then it must be essentially unique (because then it would be highly symmetric, which is not possible in 3D)? Or maybe you can argue directly that a unit distance embedding must be highly symmetric. If so, then we could skip the computational part.