# Are 4-chromatic 3-connected unit distance graphs always rigid?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coloring, rigid-transformation

At [braced heptagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954719/is-this-braced-heptagon-a-rigid-graph) we determined a graph was rigid. That graph is unit-distance, 3-connected, and 4-chromatic.  Here are some more graphs, all extremely constrained. I'm pretty sure they are all rigid graphs, but I'm not sure.

[image: 4-chromatic graphs]

Are any of these graphs not rigid?
Are all unit-distance, 3-connected, 4-chromatic graphs rigid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [programmed the first seven graphs](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/blob/7c07c1ea995d00695faa86e27c741d3bd810d43a/shibuya/pegg.py) into my new [Shibuya](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya) repository of unit-distance and integral embeddings of graphs. Strictly speaking I've only programmed six, but `{UnitDistance, {15, 1}}` contains `{UnitDistance, {12, 2}}` as a subgraph and the latter is (as will be shown) rigid, so the former is also rigid.

Using the same least-parameters method that I used to prove the rigidity of the braced heptagon, I get the following results. All the rigid graphs are first-order rigid:

| Graph | Least parameters required | Rigid? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `{UnitDistance, {9, 3}}` | 1 | yes |
| `{UnitDistance, {12, 2}}` | 2 | yes |
| Exoo–Ismailescu 17 | 2 | yes |
| Exoo–Ismailescu 19 | 2+1 | yes |
| Exoo–Ismailescu 21 | 2+1+1 | **no** (1 DOF) |
| Hochberg–O'Donnell fish | 3+1+1 | **no** (1 DOF) |

The notation $a+b+c+\cdots$ means that a subgraph was parametrised using $a$ parameters, then based on this another subgraph was parametrised using $b$ parameters and so on – the result of all these phases is the whole graph.

Exoo–Ismailescu 21 is not rigid because there are two parameters but only one constraint in the first phase; the second and third phases each have one parameter and one constraint, so they don't help with rigidity:

[image]

The reason for the "hodfish" graph not being rigid is similar, only the first phase has three parameters and two constraints:

[image]

You would have done well to check the number of edges of the two graphs shown to be non-rigid above. They fail the Laman condition (one fewer edge than $2v-3$ where $v$ is the number of vertices), which is *necessary* for a graph to be rigid.

Comment: I also found that O'Donnell 40 wasn't unit distance when I tried constructing it.  Nice work on Exoo21 and Hodfish. Do either have positions where another unit edge could be added?

Comment: @EdPegg Just look for a pair of vertices whose length changes from less than to greater than $1$ as the graph moves, then add an edge there. But for either graph there should be no edge that can be added that doesn't form a triangle or degenerates the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I get:

- the UnitDistance graphs above are rigid
- the H-O-Fish graph is *not* infinetesimally rigid, but it *might* be finitely rigid

Further, using Mathematica 12.1.0

- it doesn't seem to know the Exool... graphs
- the embedding I get for the O-40 graph is not unit-distance

I may have to update my version of Mathematica

Comment: "the embedding I get for the O-40 graph is not unit-distance" -- I'll get that fixed.

Comment: the graphs are named after Exoo and Ismailescu: this is an uppercase i, not a lowercase L. That's probably why you're not getting them in Mathematica, not the version number; my Mathematica 12.0.0.0 gets them just fine.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the spelling correction. That's what was giving me trouble there.